# TypeScript error - Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Reference'. TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I did a const to get the existing rooms in the firebase database, however when I try to use .get() on the line: const roomRef = await database.ref(`rooms/${roomCode}`).get();

it reports the following error: TypeScript error in D:/react/app/letmeask/src/pages/Home.tsx(35,65):
Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Reference'. TS2339

Can someone help me please?

full code:

async function handleJoinRoom(event: FormEvent) {
event.preventDefault();

```
    if (roomCode.trim() === '') {
        return;
    }

    const roomRef = await database.ref(`rooms/${roomCode}`).get();

    if (!roomRef.exists()) {
        alert('Room does not exists.');
        return;
    }

    if (roomRef.val().endedAt) {
        alert('Room already closed.');
        return;
    }

    history.push(`/rooms/${roomCode}`);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Hkk.png)

Comment: Is this code for Firebase?

Comment: yes, I would like to search the existing rooms in firebase database

Comment: Are you using v8 or v9 of the Firebase Javascript library?

Comment: I'm using a version 8

Answer (score 0):

According to the Firebase v8 documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_get), your code should get a ref to the database and then use `child` to reach further down the levels:

```
const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
const snapshot = await dbRef.child("rooms").child(roomCode).get();
if (!snapshot.exists()) {
 ...
```

Comment: problem solved, I installed firebase version 8.6.7 and it worked, thanks for your attention

Comment: Great. You can mark the answer as accepted using the green checkmark.